# Where can I find a C/C++ FFmpeg extensive tutorial?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, video-editing

I want to use ffmpeg (in its c library form) to split a video in more parts, recompose them and encode the final result. Something basic. But it's very difficult to find documentation or hints about this. Where should I look/ask for advice?

Comment: How about: http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html (which is basically a tutorial linked from: http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html)

Comment: have a look at this one...not up-to-date but will be a good start.
http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/ and don't forget the ffmepg doxygen doc http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/.

Comment: I found this too: http://ffmpeg.org/developer.html

Comment: +1 for the dranger.com tutorial.  It's the only one I've found that provides a step-by-step tutorial on creating a simple stripped-down application to play video while explaining every step and covering some of the API peculiarities.

Comment: Minimal runnable resize example in C at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831761/how-to-resize-a-picture-using-ffmpegs-sws-scale/36487785#36487785

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can learn a great deal from the source of the command-line utilities maintained by the FFmpeg project.

In **ffplay.c**, the **main()** will show you how to get the library initialized.  **stream_component_open()** demonstrates matching codecs to streams in the media, and **get_video_frame()** shows how to decode a packet and get its PTS (presentation time stamp).  You'll need that to time your splits correctly.

That should get you started on the decode side.  On the encode side, look at **ffmpeg.c**.  It's larger and more complicated than ffplay, but the process of encoding a frame nearly mirrors the process of decoding it, so once you have decoding working, it should make more sense.

Answer (score 4):

i was searching for a FFmpeg tutorial and php but i found the following are the best places to learn it with any language
a book i think it's the only book about FFmpeg
FFmpeg Basics: Multimedia handling with a fast audio and video encoder

[http://www.amazon.com/FFmpeg-Basics-Multimedia-handling-encoder/dp/1479327832/ref=sr_1_12?ie=UTF8&qid=1357356672&sr=8-12&keywords=ffmpeg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1479327832)

[image]

and the scond place is
http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for a good c/c++ FFmpeg tutorial for a while, and this [c/c++ ffmpeg-libav-tutorial](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial#learn-ffmpeg-libav-the-hard-way) is definitely the best I found so far. It explains how to use the FFmpeg as a library and before that gives a clear overview about video key words (like encoding, decoding, transconding, muxing exc.) which is very helpful for people who are not that familiar with videos.

In addition, this [tutorial](http://slhck.info/ffmpeg-encoding-course/#/) is great to understand the concept of video, so for those who are not familiar enough with the video world, I suggest to start with this, and only then to continue with the [c/c++ ffmpeg-libav-tutorial](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial#learn-ffmpeg-libav-the-hard-way).

Answer (score 0):

### **TLDR;**

https://github.com/ShootingKing-AM/ffmpeg-pseudocode-tutorial - A broad workflow understanding of ffmpeg-cli through loose pseudocode.

---

The best way as per FFmpeg devs is to read thorugh source of ffmpeg libav and/or ffmpeg-cli.

The goal of understanding ffmpeg-cli is to be able to to integrate FFmpeg into our projects without having to call the ffmpeg-cli in background to do multimedia operation. This is important because,

- Starting up an external executable tends to be blocked by antivirus software and can cause issues with users.
- Optimize your project specific libav usage and skip unnecessary code from ffmpeg-cli
  Also, ffmpeg official documentation being vague at best, the only option for developers looking to implement ffmpeg's libraries (libav) functionality into their code is to read the command line interface's source code.

But, Reading ffmpeg-cli's source code is very hard, because its not meant to be used as a study material for understanding how to use libav but as a optimized multimedia tool. Hence, i tried to straighten out its source code into simple pseudocode function highlighting **when and where** to call important(almost all) libav's functions, for an overall broader picture of ffmpeg workflow. For information regarding **how** to call a libav function call, one can refer to the doxygen documentation and ffmpeg-cli-source files.