# How do you resize an AVFrame?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

How do you resize an `AVFrame`? I

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
AVFrame* frame = /*...*/;

int width = 600, height = 400;
AVFrame* resizedFrame = av_frame_alloc();

auto format = AVPixelFormat(frame->format);

auto buffer = av_malloc(avpicture_get_size(format, width, height) * sizeof(uint8_t));

avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)resizedFrame, (uint8_t*)buffer, format, width, height);

struct SwsContext* swsContext = sws_getContext(frame->width, frame->height, format,
                                               width,         height,         format,
                                               SWS_BILINEAR,  nullptr,        nullptr,        nullptr);

sws_scale(swsContext, frame->data, frame->linesize, 0, frame->height, resizedFrame->data, resizedFrame->linesize);
```

But after this `resizedFrames->width`and `height` are still 0, the contents of the AVFrame look like garbage, and I get an warning that data is unaligned when I call `sws_scale`. Note: I don't want to change the pixel format, and I don't want to hard code what it is.

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831761/how-to-resize-a-picture-using-ffmpegs-sws-scale

Comment: @jimmcnamara well I appear to be doing everything the same, except having hardcoded pixel formats. So is there something wrong with the way I'm passing pixel formats? Maybe sws_scale isn't supposed to fill out the new `width` and `height` in AVFrame?

Comment: I remember copying and using the code, but it has been several years.  I do not know more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, there's a few things going on.

- [avpicture_fill()](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__picture.html#gac1b22e9b246cb8b0928cca8f5fa524d4) does not set frame->width/height/format. You have to set these values yourself.
- [avpicture_get_size()](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__picture.html#ga18a08bcb237767ef442fd5d3d1dd2084) and [avpicture_fill()](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__picture.html#gac1b22e9b246cb8b0928cca8f5fa524d4) do not guarantee alignment. The underlying functions called in these wrappers (e.g. [av_image_get_buffer_size()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__picture.html#ga24a67963c3ae0054a2a4bab35930e694) or [av_image_fill_arrays()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__picture.html#ga5b6ead346a70342ae8a303c16d2b3629)) are called with align=1, so there's no buffer alignment between lines. If you want alignment (you do), you either have to call the underlying functions directly with a different align setting, or call [avcodec_align_dimensions2()](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga34e3269dc1b9e2c98e9371241722e7e2) on the width/height and provide aligned width/height to the avpicture_*() functions. If you do that, you can also consider using [avpicture_alloc()](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__picture.html#ga03b764a93c34d00e5a33a5ebb0b4a81b) instead of [avpicture_get_size()](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__picture.html#ga18a08bcb237767ef442fd5d3d1dd2084) + [av_malloc()](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__mem.html#ga9722446c5e310ffedfaac9489864796d) + [avpicture_fill()](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__picture.html#gac1b22e9b246cb8b0928cca8f5fa524d4).

I think if you follow these two suggestions, you'll find that the rescaling works as expected, gives no warnings and has correct output. The quality may not be great because you're trying to do [bilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) scaling. Most people use [bicubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) scaling ([SWS_BICUBIC](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__libsws.html#ga02a4ee9d3c158e842941873d2cf83b9f)).

Comment: Thanks! If I use `av_image_get_buffer_size` and `av_image_fill_arrays` what alignment should I pass?

Comment: the proer align integer is , most of the time , 32