# How to convert video programmatically using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Most applications of ffmpeg both in terminal and code seem to be passing ffmpeg commands to the ffmpeg library with specific parameters. For example, you might run the following command to get an overlayed gif out of a video input and a png input:

```
-i i.mp4 -i me.png -filter_complex 'overlay' -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.gif
```

Is it possible to work with the library without using commands and only programmatically? For example, by creating an FFmpeg object, passing it relevant parameters and then reading the output file from a specific directory, preferrably using C++ or Java.

Comment: Here is a minimal runnable resize example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831761/how-to-resize-a-picture-using-ffmpegs-sws-scale/36487785#36487785

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use underlying libraries of FFmpeg programmatically (C/C++).

Check following links:

[Using libav* - FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav*)

[FFmpeg coding examples](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/tree/master/doc/examples)

Comment: If possible please post the relevant information from the links as links by themselves will be useless if they die. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely, addition to above answer, also study these on libav (FFmpeg):
 `AVFrame` structure, `AVPixelFormat`, and `libswscale` library and it's `sws_getContext` and `sws_scale` API calls.

Hope that helps.